# Are these equivalent methods of proving $\lim(\frac{b}{n})=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

For any $b\in\mathbb{R}$, prove that $\lim(\frac{b}{n})=0$

First method: $\left |\frac{b}{n}-0\right |<\varepsilon\Rightarrow \frac{|b|}{n}<\varepsilon$ so take $n_{\varepsilon}>\frac{|b|}{\varepsilon}$ then by the archimedean property $\forall n\geq n_\varepsilon$ we have that $\frac{|b|}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Second method: $\left|\frac{b}{n}-0\right |<\varepsilon_0\Rightarrow \frac{|b|}{n}<\varepsilon_0$ so take $\varepsilon_0=\varepsilon |b|$ then we have $\frac{|b|}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{|b|}<\varepsilon |b|\frac{1}{|b|}=\varepsilon$. I feel like the second method is wrong but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Actually, the Archimedean property states that there exists $n_{\varepsilon}\in \Bbb N$ such that $n_{\varepsilon}>\frac{|b|}{\varepsilon}$. By the way, what is $\epsilon_0$ in the second one?

Comment: Just some arbitrary variable larger than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to recommend either "method" but your instincts are right--it is even worse than the first.

As this is likely one of your first attempts to use the sequence definition here is a hint:  Start with assuming that someone has given you an $\epsilon$ and that you need to respond with an appropriate choice of $n_\epsilon$.  So your write up always begins

> "Let $\epsilon>0$."

Then on a scratch pad somewhere figure what you think might work for $n_\epsilon$.  Then your second sentence is

> "Let $n \geq n_\epsilon$".

Then you show that

> $$|s_n-L|<\epsilon.$$

This last step might take a while or could be as fast here.  You have nothing to work with here other than that your integer $n$ is at least big as the $n_\epsilon$ that you decided on the scratch pad would work.  Your computations on the secret scratch pad will help do this.

Then your final sentence is

> "By definition then $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=L$.

Comment: Finding a $\varepsilon$ that satisfies the equality shows the limit exists because then $\left | s_n-L\right |<\frac{1}{n}\mbox{for }n\in\mathbb{N}<\varepsilon$ right?

Comment: Never say "finding an $\epsilon$."  You don't get to find the $\epsilon$, you get to find the $n_\epsilon$ after you have been given the $\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay I will remember that but is the rest correct?

Comment: As someone currently teaching an introduction to analysis class, thanks @B.S.Thomson, I can't count how many times I have said those things in class.